# Can you run the heroku console on a follower DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a ruby on rails app deployed on heroku with a database and a follower database.

I typically do "heroku run rails console" to look around the data, and I'm wondering if there's a way that I can do it on the follower database so I don't accidentally write/delete things. I know this should be simple, but I couldn't seem to find documentation on it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this from your local console. Just fire it up:

```
rails console
```

Then you need the connection information for your follower database on heroku. You can retrieve this from https://postgres.heroku.com/databases/. Just click the relevant database and assign a hash with the following info:

```
follower_db = {:adapter  => "postgresql",
 :host     => "myhost",
 :username => "myuser",
 :password => "mypass",
 :database => "somedatabase"}
```

Now connect to this remote database from the console:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(follower_db)
```

Now any query you enter in the console will be run on this DB.

Comment: If you run `heroku config` you can find out the name of the follower and then call it directly  in code like: `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ENV['HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_FOLLOWER_URL'])`

Answer (score 5):

This will use the follower database credentials from the FOLLOWER_DATABASE_URL environment variable in your Heroku app to start up a Rails console that connects directly to the follower instead of the promoted database. Normally Rails is set up to read from DATABASE_URL by default, and this just sets it to a different value for the duration of your console session.

`heroku run 'DATABASE_URL=$FOLLOWER_DATABASE_URL rails console'`

Comment: This is the only right answer among all these other attempts to actually answer the question over the years.

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried about accidentally deleting stuff, run console with the sandbox flag

```
heroku run console --sandbox --app app-name
```

Your changes will be rolled back when your session ends.

Answer (score 0):

The console certainly has its place, but if I want to check what data is in a database then I'd prefer to look directly at it without ActiveRecord etc being in the way. I've found many instances where using the console requires that you check the generated SQL anyway to ensure that there are no scopes (for example) slipping in.

I'd suggest that you try to get into the habit of using a SQL interface (PgAdminIII perhaps) instead of the console -- an Heroku dataclip will even work if you don't want to trouble about connecting from the client (though the psql connection string is given to you from the database page).

Answer (score -2):

A database follower is a read-only copy of the master database that stays up-to-date with the master database data. As writes and other data modifications are committed in the master database the changes are streamed, in real-time, to the follower databases.

Source - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-follower-databases

Comment: Thanks, but my question is whether I can run the console on the follower database (so that only reads are allowed in the console, and I don't accidentally delete things on the master).